# In what way does the RV coefficient measure similarity?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, mathematical-statistics, cosine-similarity

The Pearson correlation coefficient is a cosine between two vectors. That's easy to understand but what happens when instead we look at the correlation between two matrices through the RV coefficient?

I get the math that goes on but intuitively what is the similarity that is being measured? I thought it would be something like average pairwise cosine between the vectors but I can't relate that to the calculations.

Comment: So you know that for matrices $A$ and $B$, [$\langle A, B \rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(A^*B)$ is an inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Inner_product), and then [$\cos \theta = \frac{\langle A, B \rangle}{\|A\|\|B\|}$ where $\|A\| = \sqrt{\langle A, A \rangle}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Norms_on_inner_product_spaces)? Instead you want intuition?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how the trace captures the relationship between all the vectors. It's the sum of $\langle x_1, y_1 \rangle + \langle x_2, y_2 \rangle + ... + \langle x_n, y_n \rangle$ but what about cross products like $\langle x_1, y_2 \rangle$ and so on? Is that similarity captured anywhere? Otherwise it would not be invariant to reordering of the columns, which seems odd.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RV_coefficient